# If a person masturbates but stops himself before he ejaculates would he need to perform ghusl for namaz?

Tags: salat, halal-haram

If a person masturbates but stops himself before he ejaculates would he need to perform ghusl for namaz? or can he perform namaz? please provide reference thank you.

Comment: No he doesn't need to perform. But if any sperm comes out after result of this masturbate(even 2 days later), he must perform ghusl.

Comment: @hellzone Ok thanks, thats what i thought but if you do find any source then put it in answer so i will accept thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ghusl is required when;

- Emission of maniy (semen) even if it is not through intercourse.(al-Mawsoo’ah al-Fiqhiyyah (31/195))

So no he doesn't need to perform. But if any sperm comes out after result of this masturbate(even 2 days later), he must perform ghusl. This point is critical because deciding if any sperm came when you pee is so hard.

**EDIT:** I need to explain last critical sentence. Even After 2 days from masturbate, sperms can leak with your urine. If that happens you need to perform ghusl. Deciding sperm leak is nearly impossible thing. So always perform ghusl when you masturbate. But my real suggestion is stop masturbating and start fasting.

Comment: It is also biologically impossible to ejaculate and urinate at the same time.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I think you didn't understand me. He is not ejeculating and urinating at the same time :) I am talking about remaining sperms from past ejeculating in penis.

Comment: I was referring to this statement of yours _"This point is critical because deciding if any sperm came when you pee is so hard."_; and now I realized you meant penis not pee :) but lets leave this topic alone (as the OP should).

Comment: @BurhanKhalid just curious as i am new to this site what is full form of OP?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid and hellzone please if you can then help me in this question of mine as well http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/11645/4510

Comment: Original Post = OP

Comment: it's important to note that not every Emission of maniy need ghusl !!

Comment: see this : https://islamqa.info/en/12317

Comment: @MustaphaElbazi He didn't said illness but talking about masturbating. I am not an islam expert. I can not explain all details but I just tried to answer his question with my experience.

Comment: @hellzone apart from fasting he can also buy or obtain as a gift a concubine if he can afford to do so.

Answer (score 0):

If you ejacuate and perform ghusul and after a while you go to pee and it comes out with the urine you dont need to to perform Ghusul one more time... thats what a scholar said once

Comment: Welcome to Islam SE. Answers should be elaborate and focused on addressing the question. Claims should be supported by evidence. Please visit our [tour] in the [help], and refer to [answer]. Please provide the name of the scholar who said so, and cite the source.

Answer (score -1):

Ghusl is only required when you experience feelings of pleasure; so by ejaculating. Otherwise, you can perform wudhu instead.

Comment: Welcome to Islam SE. Answers should be elaborate and focused on addressing the question. Claims should be supported by evidence. Please visit our [tour] in the [help], and refer to [answer].